# After clean install I cannot login using my chosen password

Tags: 19.04

I've performed a clean Ubuntu 19.04 installation 3 times now and every time after the first reboot when the installation is done I get stuck on the login screen due to incorrect password.

The first couple of times I thought I must have been crazy and entered a password I cannot remember - but the third time I even noted down the password I chose to be 100% sure.

My first thought is that during the installation, selecting my native keyboard layout (Swedish) isn't being applied after the installation, but even using a US layout I find myself greeted by the incorrect password message.

The third time I deselected the option to encrypt the drive, hoping that would be the cause, but no cigar.

If I use my old USB drive and install 18.04 instead everything works as intended.

Is there a workaround or a known bug that is causing this?

Comment: Does your password contain non-ASCII characters? Does it contain non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Nope, there are only ASCII characters - it does contain non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: And you are sure that you are using exactly the **same keyboard layout**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that sometimes the installer doesnt honor keyboard layout and defaults back to US during my use of a dvorak keyboard. If you keep the default keyboard layout as a US layout yet type in your password as if you were using a swedish keyboard, does your new install accept that password?

Comment: This seems to be true. I've probably tried installing Ubuntu 5 times since last night and the installer indeed does not honor the layout chosen in step 2, even if the layout is working for the duration of that dialog. However, I've not yet figured out which layout is applied, it's not US - that much I know. I've successfully installed and logged in now, by choosing a password with only alpha-num on a dvorak keyboard.